# Error : rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments:

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my project i have one publisher file ( publish rpm for a wheel) and one subscriber file (calculate the speed of the wheel based on rpm value )

the code works fine until i try to publish the speed to another node called "speed" and it gives me this error rospy.init_node() has already been called with different arguments:

the subscriber file  code as below:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String , Float64
import math


def calculate_speed(rpm):
    radius = 5.1
    speed = rpm.data*2.0*(math.pi)*radius
    print(speed)

def rpm_subscriber():
    rospy.init_node('rpm_Subscriber_Node')
    rospy.Subscriber('rpm' , Float64 , calculate_speed)

def speed_publish():
    rospy.init_node("speed_Publisher_Node")
    pub = rospy.Publisher("speed" , Float64 , queue_size=10)

    rate = rospy.Rate(5)
    pub.publish(speed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rpm_subscriber()
    speed_publish()

    print('DONE')
```

please help i have been stuck here for an hours

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371673/error-:-rospy.init_node()-has-already-been-called-with-different-arguments:/) by [tq1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/69912/tq1992/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the error is pretty clear. You have two calls to `rospy.init_node()` in your code. One executable equals one ROS node, and should thus only have one call to `rospy.init_node()`. You'd need to split your code into two executables, if this should be two nodes...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tq1992](https://answers.ros.org/users/69912/tq1992/) on 2021-12-21**:
thanks man